# Printing a page using Bootstrap on a Drupal site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, printing, drupal-7

I am building a site on Drupal 7 and I am using Bootstrap. 
When trying to print the page, everything looks like one big mess (you can see that on the print preview).

How can I fix this?

Example page:
 http://newcmsqa2.discountbank.co.il/node/420

Comment: Watching this one. I am in the same boat. It looks like it's only taking the mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

finally got it. need to add media query to fix page size.
here is an example for wide screen measurments:

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: 1240px 1610px;
    margin: 52px;
  }
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

also, this is the place to decide if there are certain blocks you want to hide or change size for print like the navbar or other elements.